# Be + noun/adjective + in + doing

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the "in" in these sentences?

> 1- There is ***no shame in wanting*** to be successful.
>
> 2- There is ***no advantage in working*** at that company
>
> 3- She realized there was ***no use in arguing*** with him.
>
> 4- Mary is ***wrong in saying***, 'Jack is stupid'.

Can I omit the "in" or change with another preposition?

As:

> 1'- There is ***no shame wanting*** to be succesful
>
> 2'- There is ***no advantage working*** at that company.
>
> 3'- She realized there was ***no use of arguing*** with him.
>
> 4'- Mary is ***wrong about saying***, "Jack is stupid".

Answer (score 1):

The gerund used in the  original sentences works as a *noun* expressing an action. A speaker can find something good or not so good ***in*** that action.

Replacing or removing that preposition is sometimes possible, but not in all these examples. The first sentence after modification at least can get a second meaning and sound like '*There is no shame that wants to be successful*'. Same with the second sentence (like, *advantages don't work at that company*). '*Use of arguing*' can be treated as a general concept (e. g. *what's the use of arguing?*) but the preposition **in** works better **in** the situation of her '*arguing with him*'. In sentence 4 '**about**' is grammatically possible but would make it unclear what was wrong: *she shouldn't have said a known thing or she was wrong about Jack*.

Comment: Hi, I want to ask one more thing. What did you mean by saying "...can find good or not so good ***in*** that action" . What does "in" mean here?  "inside the action" (metaphorical)  or "during the action" or something else?